# Finding the largest resolution from set of resolution

Tags: php, regex

I have set of strings like the following:

```
1024 x 768  
1280 x 960  
1280 x 1024     
1280 x 800 widescreen   
1440 x 900 widescreen   
1680 x 1050 widescreen
```

How to I discover the largest resolution of it? By largest I mean the one with the highest height and longest width. In above case `1680 x 1050` is the largest as it has the highest dimensions and we can create all other resolution from it.

My plan of action to solve this was to take out the resolution values, but I only simple regex and it is not enought to extract the resolution out. Then I do not know how to use the height and width to determine the largest resolution dimensions.

Comment: Do you need regex to get the dimensions? Have you tried splitting by space and taking the first and third elements of the resulting array, you multiply. Store that value somewhere and later compare it with all the other resolutions.

Comment: @Jerry, Yes I did but the values have many variables and it became junk code instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collect the strings in an array, like so

```
$resolutions = array(
    '1024 x 768',
    '1680 x 1050 widescreen',
    '1280 x 960',
    '1280 x 1024',
    '1280 x 800 widescreen',
    '1440 x 900 widescreen'
);
```

You can use [`sscanf`](http://php.net/sscanf) to extract the width and height from the strings. You need to multiply width and height to determine which resolution has the most pixels/is the largest resolution.

```
$getPixels = function($str) {
    list($width, $height) = sscanf($str, '%d x %d');
    return $width * $height;
};
```

Then either use [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/array_reduce)

```
echo array_reduce(
    $resolutions, 
    function($highest, $current) use ($getPixels) {
        return $getPixels($highest) > $getPixels($current) 
            ? $highest 
            : $current;
    }
);
```

Or [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) the array

```
usort(
    $resolutions, 
    function($highest, $current) use ($getPixels) {
        return $getPixels($highest) - $getPixels($current);
    }
);

echo end($resolutions);
```

to get the highest resolution *1680 x 1050 widescreen*

Answer (score 0):

You just need to multiply width by height to find the resolution.

Note that you might not have an item having both the max width and the max height in your list.

PHP extraction :

```
// I assume your set of string is an array
$input = <<<RES
1024 x 768  
1280 x 960  
1280 x 1024     
1680 x 1050 widescreen
1280 x 800 widescreen   
1440 x 900 widescreen   
RES;

$resolutions = explode( "\n", $input );


// Build a resolution name / resolution map
$areas = array();

foreach( $resolutions as $resolutionName )
{
    preg_match( '/([0-9]+) x ([0-9]+)/', $resolutionName, $matches ); 

    // Affect pixel amount to each resolution string
    $areas[$resolutionName] = $matches[1]*$matches[2];
}

// Sort on pixel amount
asort($areas);

// Pick the last item key
$largest = end( array_keys($areas) );


echo $largest;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, to get the maximum resolution:

```
$resolutions = array(
"1024 x 768",  
"1280 x 960",  
"1280 x 1024",     
"1280 x 800 widescreen",   
"1440 x 900 widescreen",   
"1680 x 1050 widescreen"
);

$big = 0;
$max = 0;

foreach($resolution as $res){
$sides = explode(' ', $res);
if(($sides[0] * $sides[2]) > $big)
    $max = $res;
}
```

Or, if you want to hold just the index of max resolution, you can change the code to this:

```
$big = 0;
$max = 0;
$i = 0;

foreach($resolution as $res){
$sides = explode(' ', $res);
if(($sides[0] * $sides[2]) > $big)
    $max = $i;
$i++;
}
```